# Setting Search and Measure in QField

Tags: qgis, qfield

On the QField documentation page I saw this

> **Configure search in QGIS**
>   -Choose the layers which are searchable in Project > Project Properties‣> Identify Layers
>   -Define the display expression for the concerned layers, this will be used for searching for features. This is configured under Vector Layer Properties‣> Display page

where do I find the "Identify Layers" and Vector Layer Properties options? Is it on QGIS Desktop or QField? Because on QGIS (I'm using version 3.4) there's no Identify Layer option.

PS: when exporting my QGIS project for QField (1.1.0) the search and measure tools are available, is this a fix or can it be customized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selection *which layers* should be searchable is done in the project properties

[image]

The selection *what* should be searchable in the layer (attribute selection) is done in the layer properties. Only layers which have "Searchable" checked will be searched.

[image]

The measure tool is always available