# Find and display an entity QField

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qfield

I tried all the parameters imaginable,
I have a layer with several entities,
and I would like to search for an entity and display it in QField.
Someone could give me a tutorial or some indication to get there?

Comment: Searchable is set in the QGIS project properties > https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337148/setting-search-and-measure-in-qfield

Comment: Thank you for you answer